# A compact set $K\subseteq X$ is contained in the polar of a neighborhood of $0\in X^\prime$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, weak-topology

Let $(X,X^\prime)$ be a dual pair, where $X$ is a topological vector space (over the real field) endowed with the weak topology, and the topological dual $X^\prime$ is endowed with the weak$^\star$-topology.

Fix also a (weakly-)compact set $K\subseteq X$.

> **Question.** Is it true that there exists a (weak$^\star$-)open neighborhood $V$ of $0 \in X^\prime$ such that $K$ is contained in the absolute polar of $V$, namely,
> $$
> K\subseteq V^\circ:=\{x \in X: |\langle x,x^\prime\rangle|\le 1 \text{ for all }x^\prime \in V\}\,\,\,\,?
> $$

*Attempt.* I thought to use something like $V:=K^\circ$ (which, however, is nonempty, convex, circled, weak$^\star$-closed, and contains $0 \in X^\prime$) and, then, to use the Bipolar theorem which tells us that $K^{\circ\circ}$ (namely, $V^\circ$) is the circled weakly convex hull of $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an open neighborhood $V$ can only be found if $K$ is contained in some finite dimensional subspace of $X$.

To see why,
suppose that $V$ exists. By definition of the weak* topology, there are vectors $x_1,x_2,\ldots , x_n\in X$, and $\varepsilon >0$, such that
$$
  U:= \{x'\in  X': |\langle x_i, x'\rangle |<\varepsilon \}\subseteq V.
  $$

Defining $y_i=\displaystyle\frac{2x_i}{\varepsilon }$, notice that, for all $x'$ in $X'$, one has that
$$
  |\langle y_i, x'\rangle |\leq 1 \Rightarrow   |\langle x_i, x'\rangle |\leq \frac\varepsilon 2 < \varepsilon .
  $$
This implies that
$$
  \{y_1,y_2,\ldots , y_n\}^\circ \subseteq U\subseteq V,
  $$
whence
$$
  K\subseteq V^\circ \subseteq    \{y_1,y_2,\ldots , y_n\}^{\circ \circ }.
  $$
Since the latter is the the circled, weakly closed convex hull of $\{y_1,y_2,\ldots , y_n\}$, which in turn is contained
in $\text{span}\{y_1,y_2,\ldots , y_n\}$, we are done.

Comment: If I understood correctly, what you proved is: the polar of every neighborhood of $0 \in X$ (which is weak$^\star$-compact) is always contained in a finite dimensional vector space of $X^\prime$. Do you have a reference for it?

Comment: I don't think I have a precise reference for this specific fact, but this general sort of results may be found quite elegantly described in the book "Topological Vector Spaces" by H.H. Schaefer and M.P. Wolff, mainly in the chapter on Duality.

Comment: I have been searching through the book (it is a nice one), but I didn't find it. In any case, thank you for the answer